# Debezium Sql Server Connector do not receive updates after some inactive time

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka-connect, cdc, debezium

I have running a docker container with Kafka-connect and debezium sql server connector.

When I launch the connector it takes the snapshot of database and sends to kafka messages about the data that database has in that moment.

If i start doing updates, inserts and deletes in the database immediately after those snapshot and messages sent to kafka the connector is fully responsive and receives the updates of the database.

If i left the connector running without any changes in database like 30 minutes, 1 hour it looks like that the thread of the connector is sleeping and takes a while to receive the new updates. The last test I made, the connector took 20 minutes to wake up and receive the new updates, but once it wakes up is fully responsive.

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628165/debezium-mongodb-connector-0-3-6-automatically-stops-tailing-mongodb-until-res#_=_) in stack overflow similar to this one but for debezium mongodb connector. The solution described in that question do not work for me because I cannot restart the connector task because i do not know when changes in database will occur, because it is a legacy application that makes database changes.

Does anybody know any other alternative to keep connector task synchronized/responsive with database changes?

Connector configuration:

```
{
    "name": "myConnector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "asw.myConnector",
        "internal.key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "table.whitelist": "dbo.user,dbo.test_table1,dbo.test_table2",
        "value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
        "tombstones.on.delete": "false",
        "schema.registry.url": "http://xxxx:8081",
        "schema.registry.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
        "database.history.kafka.recovery.poll.interval.ms": "20000",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "errors.log.enable": "true",
        "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "database.user": "sa",
        "database.dbname": "myDb",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "xxxx:9092",
        "database.server.name": "asw",
        "database.port": "1433",
        "key.converter.basic.auth.user.info": "xxxx",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://xxxx:8081",
        "internal.key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.basic.auth.user.info": "xxxx",
        "database.hostname": "xxxx",
        "database.password": "xxxx",
        "internal.value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "internal.value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info": "xxxx",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://xxxx:8081",
        "key.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
        "transforms": "InsertTenantId, InsertInstanceId, ValueToKey",
        "transforms.InsertTenantId.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
        "transforms.InsertTenantId.static.field": "tenant_id",
        "transforms.InsertTenantId.static.value": "xxxx",
        "transforms.InsertInstanceId.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
        "transforms.InsertInstanceId.static.field": "instance_id",
        "transforms.InsertInstanceId.static.value": "xxxx",
        "transforms.ValueToKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
        "transforms.ValueToKey.fields":"tenant_id,instance_id"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please confirm that the changes applied were available in change tables on a short notice?

Comment: Yes, the changes were applied in change tables right after the update.

Comment: You can also enable `TRACE` level logging. This way we would see if Debezium does not read the changes or Kafka Connect does not read this changes from Debezium. The downside is that the logging requirements are huge! You'd need to use `RollingFileAppender` and compress the rolled out files.

Comment: Hey @IvoCorreia I have a similar problem with SqlServer Debezium connector. Did you ever resolve this?